# PHP str_replace array stored in text file

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I'm trying to use PHP's `str_replace` to replace a string based on two arrays which are both stored in an external text file.

```
//All codes listed in a txt file
$codes = file('aircodes.txt');

//Full name replacements
$full  = file('fullcodes.txt');

$string = "BUF YUL YYZ";
$newstring = str_replace($codes, $full, $string);
echo $newstring;
```

Contents of my `aircodes.txt` file:

```
BUF
YUL
YYZ
```

Contents of my `fullcodes.txt` file:

```
Buffalo
Montreal
Toronto
```

Though, none of my codes get replaced with the city name. If I remove everything but one line from each of the text files, it works.

Comment: `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you still have a new line character in each element expect in last one (Means in your string it won't find: `BUF\n` or `YUL\n`, BUT `YYZ`). So just append a [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php#refsect1-function.file-parameters) to ignore these characters, like this:

```
$codes = file('aircodes.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
//...                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ See here
$full  = file('fullcodes.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

You can also see the characters if you do a `var_dump($codes)`:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "BUF
"
//^ See here new line character
  [1]=>
  string(5) "YUL
"
//^ See here new line character
  [2]=>
  string(3) "YYZ"
//              ^ See here NO new line character
}
```